# How to display Extent Report with japanese? ( JAVA )

Tags: cjk, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I working with client Japanese. So how i can to display Extent report to japanese?

I'm try this config but it didn't work

`public static final ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports(); ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/extentV5/ExtentReport " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss.dd.MM.yyyy").format(new java.util.Date()) + ".html"); reporter.loadXMLConfig (new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\extent-config.xml"));`

`<extentreports> <configuration> <language>ja</language> </configuration> </extentreports>`